# Using @import for google fonts is not working on internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

I am trying to use google fonts on my web but I have an issue with internet explorer. I am using @import, and when I google it I see that people use it this way:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

The thing is that the link i got looks like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/opensanshebrew.css);
```

When I open my web on IE there is no text at all.

Do I have to get the webfont files? Or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you declaring the font in a CSS file? `body { font-family: open-sans; }` etc.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer do you use ?

Comment: Have you followed these directions?  http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Comment: Use this jsFiddle to check in your IE.  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/c662j/

Comment: No, use *this* jsFiddle to check in your IE: https://jsfiddle.net/f365cn7j/ (if the !!! have round dots and sharp top edges, you're good, otherwise you're using Arial or something)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hia
I've had the same issue, so I've created a new web version of this font which works great with IE.
You can download it Here:
http://assafk.com/staff/open_sans_hebrew/Opes_Sans_Hebrew_Fixed.rar
Thanks!
Assaf

**after you download the files in the rar, add this css to use it:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-lightitalic-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-lightitalic-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-lightitalic-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-lightitalic-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-light-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-light-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-light-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-light-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-italic-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-italic-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-italic-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-regular-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-regular-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-regular-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-bolditalic-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-bolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-bolditalic-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-bolditalic-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-bold-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-bold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-bold-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Hebrew';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.eot);
    src: url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
    url(opensanshebrew-extrabold-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Toda Raba! You saved me

Comment: it works but is heavy on the site load.
 this line worked for me, but the font looks bad
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/alefhebrew.css);

Comment: איזה אלוף אתה... תודה גבר

Comment: I recently noticed this fixed version has a buggy `extra-bold` weight. The letters are misaligned and it just looks bad. Other weights might be affected as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sheriffderek is right in the comments on one of these answers - **you shouldn't be using @import** - but didn't explain him/herself. You likely have a cross domain issue and both IE and Firefox blocking remote requests made like this. You have to associate the content type with your remote request so that it isn't blocked.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The `'type'` parameter here is key - it is what allows the remote request to happen in IE and FF. CSS is allowed to do this kind of cross domain linking, as it is judged by the W3C gods to be a low security risk.

Check these links out for more information on CORS:

- IE's explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Mozilla's thoughts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy
- The JS side of implementation (if you are really curious): http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: This is not the issue everyone is having. Assaf Katz has it right.

Comment: What does this have to do with an @import declaration ?

Comment: @NathanHornby - the O.P. shouldnt be using @import. And if you don't use at import, you need to be sure you include the `type` param in the remote stylesheet declaration so that it does not run against CORS.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use :

`<link href='link-to-your-css/file.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

[Don't use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/)

Comment: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: I think you missed the point. Check out the font page: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Comment: Why don't use @import! then how do you want to add CDN fonts to wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the [Open Sans Hebrew](https://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) font itself, a problem that has been reported several times on the [Google Fonts Early Access Discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/early-access-fonts) forum, with no solution posted so far. Consider using some other “Early Access” (i.e., experimentanl) font, such as Alef Hebrew.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the issue. i have tried to upload my web without linking the fonts at all (i have downloaded them locally on my PC), and still i only get that issue on explorer. on chrome FF opera and safari it works well. thanks!

Comment: See @Assaf Katz's answer, he solved it for me. Maybe change it to accepted?