# Text isn't shown (randomly) on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

Once every couple of days the site is loading without the text only on IE and without any error.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you just can't see error messages, since there's no text ...

Comment: I don't see any error in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue [Using @import for google fonts is not working on internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438319/using-import-for-google-fonts-is-not-working-on-internet-explorer).  It seems like there is a known bug in IE+Win7 that can't load these fonts.